# how to show validation error from save overrided model?

Tags: django

i use Django 1.6

I overrided save method of Model.
when I catched the error.

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # something
        catch:
            raise ValidationError("some error message")
        else:
            super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I use the model from my form.
but, the the error shows Django's server error.
But i want to show like validation error like form.
how to show error like validation error in from model's save?

Comment: You should do the validation in your form.

Comment: Thank you for replying.So, I can't use model?

Comment: You could post your view and form for that model. That surely can help to look up for a solution!.